# Tutorial install Redmine on Debian?

Tags: ruby, debian, redmine

There are a lot of tutorials for installing `redmine`, but most are out of date or incorrect.

I have a `Debian 6.0.8` and use `Apache`.

Are there any good, complete tutorials on installing `redmine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this tutorial :

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_210_on_Debian_Squeeze_with_Apache_Passenger

Works perfectly, just some precisions :

- Don't forget to remplace `mysql` to  `mysql2` in the file :
  `database.yml`
- Don't forget to install `active-mysql-adapter`, before you migrate the database :

  `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter`
- And put the right for apache : `chown -R www-data:www-data redmine`
- Otherwise, you also need to update some packaged with `bundle`, but `bundle` explain the commands for you, so no worry.